# sql server listen on multiple ports

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a push subscriber in transactional replication (and the distributor is the publisher), in this subscriber I configured sql server port on 1433, and I have a web application which connect to this subscriber database, and I want to use any port but not 1433, Can I configure SQL server to listen to two different ports one will be used in replication from distributor IP (which stay 1433) , and the other for web request (from web server IP), and how to do that ??

In case of a single port, If the default port of sql server(1433) is changed this will affect on replication cause subscriber and publisher listening on the same port, is this right ??

Answer (score 4):

Yes, SQL Server can be configured to listen on multiple IPs and multiple ports. Read [Configure the Database Engine to Listen on Multiple TCP Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189310.aspx).